# Setting active navigation menu item

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm playing with bootstrap 3 for the first time with asp.net.  I've got a basic nav pill menu where you simply add "class='active'" on whichever nav pill you want to have the selected, like so:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to know if there is a best practice for setting which LI get's the active class.  I have a working solution but it feels clunky.

In the markup code, I am using literals:

```
<li <%=NavHomeItem%> id="HomeItem" ><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
<li <%=NavProfileItem%> id="ProfileItem"><a href="Profile.aspx">Profile</a></li>
```

In the code-behind, I set the literal based on which page is requested:

```
public String NavHomeItem = "";
public String NavProfileItem = "";
public String NavMessagesItem = "";

private void SetNavigationHtml()
{
    var url = Page.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    switch (url.ToLower()) {
        case "/profile.aspx": 
            NavProfileItem = "class=\"active\"";
            break;
        case "/messages.aspx":
            NavMessagesItem = "class=\"active\"";
            break;
        default:
            NavHomeItem = "class=\"active\"";
            break;
    }
}
```

Is there a more professional way to handle this?  Open to any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do in one of my projects - which is a very simple solution, is that on page for every top-level view - so like 'Home', 'Profile' in your case, I just have a simple JQuery snippet that sets specific pill to active, something along those lines:

> $("#HomeItem").addClass("active")

That way, setting active pill, is done completely client-side.